inter core interconnect Checking in simple Slices of TPU
ICI (inter core interconnects) offers a very fast connectivity with TPUs (that is connected with different hosts) and thus also increase its total available memory for TPU calculations (I guess!). Will it already be initiated by launching a TPU pod, or we have to use Tools like Ray Cluster etc. to get ICI among the TPUs?
I tried v2-32 slice but I found no way to check this explicitly say with Jax? in other words, Can we use Jax scripts to check ICI in a Pod/Slice?
